# Set 4 column odd even grid using nth-child and select items 2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18, 20

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have added static code for what I am trying to achieve, but I need this to be dynamic so I can detect these children 2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18, 20... using "nth-child". All the child elements must be in a single parent div and not in different rows of divs.

1 **2** 3 **4**
**5** 6 **7** 8
9 **10** 11 **12**
**13** 14 **15** 16
17 **18** 19 **20**

I am creating something like above structure and wanted to apply same background to Bold text using nth-child only.

```css
.PlayersGridItem__row {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.PlayersGridItem__item {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid red;
  background: #cccccc;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.PlayersGridItem__item:nth-child(2)
  {
  background:#FFF;
  }
  
  .PlayersGridItem__item:nth-child(4)
  {
  background:#FFF;
  }
  
.PlayersGridItem__item:nth-child(5)
  {
  background:#FFF;
  }
  
.PlayersGridItem__item:nth-child(7)
  {
  background:#FFF;
  }
```

```html
<div class="PlayersGridItem__row">
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="PlayersGridItem__item">
              <div class="PlayersGridItem__player-name">
                Noah Andrews
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: This isn't a hugely helpful question... What does your HTML look like?

Comment: please post your markup. Is this a list? a table? a `Grid/Flexbox` layout?

Answer (score 1):

You could try targeting odd/even rows and their odd/even children. Assuming each row of numbers is a separate `.row` and each number is a `.column`:

```
.row:nth-child(odd) .column:nth-child(even),
.row:nth-child(even) .column:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```